# SQL Subquery empty return

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm sorry for the title, but I didn't find a better one.
My problem is the following:
I want to select all fields from table "log" where field "user" is "user1" or "user2 in "friendships". My query looks like this, but it returns a zero value:

```
    SELECT * FROM `log` 
    WHERE `user` = ANY(SELECT `user1` FROM `friendships` 
                       WHERE (`user1` = 1 OR `user2` = 1) AND `active` = 1) 
    OR `user` = ANY(SELECT `user2` FROM `friendships` 
                    WHERE (`user1` = 1 OR `user2` = 1) AND `active` = 1) 
    GROUP BY `arguments` 
    ORDER BY `created` DESC
```

If I used only one subquery it works, but I need the second field too. And there are more values (that's the reason why I use subqueries with ANY and not JOIN).
I hope somebody finds my error :).

Comment: What database is this? Oracle?

Comment: @Bohemian - no tool, just plain old me. A formatting I picked up from Quassnoi and stuck on me but I doubt it'l stick on you :). Feel free to reformat to your likings.

Comment: Well, OK I will format it the way I think is best. You can roll back the change as you like of course. Note the slight refactoring to simplify and remove unneeded brackets

Comment: See my answer for an even simpler refactoring

Comment: @Bohemian: You changed the original query, not just reformatted it!

Comment: I "changed" it, but it is identical in execution. I changed `= ANY` to `IN` and changed `(user1 = 1 or user1 = 2)` to `user1 in (1, 2)`... so what? It will actually perform better anyway

Comment: @Bohemian: No, originally it was `user1 = 1 or user2 = 1`.

Comment: @Bohemian - this is certainly less verbose but also (to me) less readable. To each his own...

Comment: Sorry @Bohemian, I'm reverting this to a version that keeps the code intact, and the one too that applies just a basic formatting to the original one-liner (sorry Lieven too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope this works:

```
SELECT *
FROM `log` INNER JOIN `friendships` on
    `log`.`user` = `friendships`.`user`
WHERE `friendships`.`user` in (1,2)
            AND
      `friendships`.`active` = 1
ORDER BY `created` DESC
```

**PS:** Can post the schema (or *structure*) of your table?

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM `log` INNER `friendships` on
        `log`.`user` = `friendships`.`user1`
    WHERE `friendships`.`user1` in (1,2) 
            AND
          `friendships`.`active` = 1
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM `log` INNER `friendships` on
        `log`.`user` = `friendships`.`user2`
    WHERE `friendships`.`user2` in (1,2) 
            AND
          `friendships`.`active` = 1
) as iTable
ORDER BY iTable.`created` DESC
```

Comment: Structure is here: http://nopaste.me/paste/6149289184f2157074c90c
Sorry for link, but I can't use code-tag here.

Thanks for help. The posted query doesn't work because I need user1 and user2 (row 2 and 3). I will search and read and try to edit query to my needs.

Comment: No it's not what I need. The 1 in my query (what user1 or user2 has to be) is a user-id. The user-id isn't static (just a test with test-user).

Comment: @user1141147 the 1, 2 can be replace the your `userID`, you can still modify it. i updated the query.

Comment: thank you. The second one seems to the right one, but I get an error (MySQL):
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`friendships` on `log`.`user` = `friendships`.`user1` WHERE `frien' at line 5

//Edit: I tried to connect my 2 queries with UNION, but there is an empty result again :S.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try a different approach, something like this perhaps:

```
SELECT *
FROM `log`
WHERE `user` IN (
  SELECT `user1` FROM `friendships` WHERE `user2` = @user AND `active` = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT `user2` FROM `friendships` WHERE `user1` = @user AND `active` = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT @user
)
GROUP BY
  `arguments`
ORDER BY
  `created` DESC
```

Although, to tell the truth, I would avoid selecting columns that are neither aggregated nor included in GROUP BY in a query like this, even though MySQL would allow me to do that.

Another alternative:

```
SELECT *
FROM `log`
WHERE `user` IN (
  SELECT
    CASE `user1` WHEN @user THEN `user2` ELSE `user1` END AS `user`
  FROM `friendships`
  WHERE (`user1` = @user OR `user2` = @user) AND `active` = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT @user
)
GROUP BY
  `arguments`
ORDER BY
  `created` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. I found my stupid failure. I want the value for every found ID and this was the reason why it didn't worked for me. I solved it with 2 queries and UNION ALL.

Comment: Thanks all. The IN-Statement was what I needed. And for sure the UNION too :).

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the OR into a single list using union:

```
select * 
from `log` 
where `user` in (
    select user1
    from friendships 
    where user1 in (1, 2) and active)
    union
    select user2
    from friendships 
    where `user1` in (1, 2) and active
)
group by arguments
order by `created` desc
```

or use a union on a standard join

```
select * from (
select l.* 
from `log` l
join friendships f on l.user = f.user1 and f.user1 in (1, 2) and f.active
union
select l.* 
from `log` l
join friendships f on l.user = f.user2 and f.user2 in (1, 2) and f.active
) x
group by arguments
order by `created` desc
```